# How to return all polygons that intersects a linestring?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I'm trying to return all polygons that intersect a linestring as a `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION`.

This is the query I've tried so far. It returns all the polygons that intersect a linestring but in separate rows. How can I combine all the results in the query to return a `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION`

```
SELECT poly.the_geog FROM ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;LINESTRING(85.269150 23.157234,85.278541 23.101098,85.286367 23.047280,85.287737 23.006227)') as road, poly 
WHERE ST_Intersects(
    road,poly.the_geog
    );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ST_Collect](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Collect.html) to aggregate the geometries into a collection.

```
SELECT ST_Collect(poly.the_geog) ...
```